# Multiprocessing example not giving the desired output python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I was going through the documentation of the Multiprocessing library in python.

This is the example what I am trying to run:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

The example is taken from the following link: [Multiprocessing Doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html)

I am getting the following error while running the above program:

```
Process SpawnPoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 345, in get
    return ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
Process SpawnPoolWorker-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
Process SpawnPoolWorker-5:
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 345, in get
    return ForkingPickler.loads(res)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 345, in get
    return ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

And the process is not ending as well. If I try pressing enter, the python crashes but the program is still on.

Kindly, let me know what I need to do to resolve the problem.

Comment: What is the name of the file you stored your program in?

Comment: I did store the program in file. I directly have ran the program from the Python shell.

Comment: What is the name of the file you stored your program in?

Comment: I get the same issue on Python 3.5 in IPython and Python interpreters, but no issue when I run using `python filename.py` from the command line. Try running the code that way?

Comment: @JohnZwinck oops, srry .. my typo... I wanted to say: I didn't store the program in file. I directly have ran the program from the Python shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python multiprocessing works by loading the program again in a separate Python process (i.e. another interpreter instance).

You are trying to use `multiprocessing` directly from the REPL, by typing in the code, which won't work, because there is no file for the other processes to load.

You'll need to store the code in a file.